# How to use multiple models in single view asp.net core 2.2 mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use two models in 1 view,both models return different data,first contains `winners list` and second contains `challenges`.
I have created custom view model:

```
  public class CustomViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Challenges> challenges { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChallengesWinners> challengeswinners { get; set; }
}
```

and controller `ChallengesController`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()

{

 var model = new CustomViewModel
 {
  challenges = _context.Challenges.ToListAsync(),  //showing error here red line conversion error
  challengeswinners = _context.Challenges.ToListAsync()//showing error here red line conversion error
 };

return View("Index", model);
}
```

and view contains:

```
@model CustomViewModel
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutChallenges.cshtml";
 }
<html>
<body>
   @foreach (var item in Model.challenges)
   {
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ChallengeName)
    }
   @foreach (var item in Model.challengeswinners)
   {
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ChallengeName)
    }
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: challenges = _context.Challenges.ToListAsync(),  //showing error here red line conversion error
  challengeswinners = _context.Challenges.ToListAsync()//showing error here red line conversion error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var model = new CustomViewModel
 {
     challenges = await _context.Challenges.ToListAsync(),  
     challengeswinners = await _context.Challenges.ToListAsync()
 };
```

Comment: You awesome ! Great ! Thank you Ricardo Peres :) Something was missing